# Setup Scheduled Job and custom ribbon in XM Cloud to perform sync action

Tags: powershell-extensions, xm-cloud, scheduled-tasks

our team has recently acquired Sitecore XM Cloud, and I am completely new to the Sitecore.
We need to implement a feature where a button in the Content Editor allows marketers or developers to synchronize data with a remote Dynamics 365 database when clicked. I did some research and looks like I need to write a sync function in Powershell and attach it as command for that ribbon? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Additionally, we need to establish a nightly task that automatically syncs data with the Dynamics 365 database (so the items under that data folder in content tree will be updated) . Can we set up such a scheduled task in XM Cloud from backend to achieve this requirement? I would greatly appreciate any assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to handle the Content Editor integrations (Ribbon button) and custom scheduled tasks.

There is a wealth of information on this site and in the [official documentation](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this within XM Cloud. You need to create a service externally that does the sync via the GraphQL Mutations API to update the Sitecore items.

You can use Sitecore Connect for this, or a similar service, or you can write an Azure Function, external service etc... that runs on a schedule and performs the updates.

This is not something to do within the CM.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't attach a powershell extensions into the Ribbon button in Content Editor? instead I should use SitecoreConnect / Azure Function to get data from external sources (in this case Azure DB hosted) and then making Graphql mutation api to update it? 

Does it mean I need to write a custom resolver in the sitecore backend? Or everything should be handled in the Azure Function / SitecoreConnect.  

Sorry for noob question as I completely new to Sitecore ecosystem. Thank you very much for you help, appreciate it

Comment: But I thought mutation is not allowed in Experience Edge in Xm Cloud? as it only for  exposes data via GraphQL. Sorry If i'm wrong

Comment: You can use the Admin API: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/admin-api.html